I want to write the input from a method int an array using a for loop, but I keep running into errors
public class {

 //these are the arrays I want to store the info in   
  
    public static int NumberOfTasks =0;
    public static String taskNameArray[];
    public static int taskNumberAray[];
    public static String taskDescriptionArray[];
    public static String developerDetailsArray[];
    public static int taskDurationArray[];
    public static String taskIDArray[];
    public static String StatusArray[];
    }
    public satic void main(String[] args){

    addTask(HowManyTasks);
    }

     public static void addTasks(int HowManyTasks){

     //When I run the file i get an error that says  Cannot store to object array because                      poe_part_2.Task.taskNameArray" is null
 

           
    for(int i=0 ; i<HowManyTasks ; i++){
     taskNameArray[i]= taskName();
     developerDetailsArray[i] = developerDetails();
     taskDurationArray[i] = taskDuration();
     String taskDescription = taskDescriptionArray[i];
     while(!(checkTaskDescription(taskDescription = takeTaskDescription())))
     {System.out.println("Try again");}
     StatusArray[i] =  Status();
     taskNumberAray[i] =  taskNumber();
     taskIDArray[i] = createTaskID(NumberOfTasks);
 
   }
   }

I tried commenting out some lines but I realised that all the arays have this problem(they are         not writing to the arrays that I have set in the public class)
I tried to switch how I assigned the input to the array but complaints from the compiler quickly shut that idea down(so i did this:  taskName() =  taskNameArray[i];)

You're only declaring the arrays. Of course they are null. You need to initialize them too. public static String taskNameArray[];is effectively the same as public static String taskNameArray[] = null;

There are other compiler errors here... Ideally, you'd make a standalone Task class then have one array of Task objects, rather than parallel arrays

When I run the file I can’t run the file because of syntax errors. If you want our help with errors that show up while running your program, please post a program that we can run. See [mre].

You need to actually instantiate the arrays before you use them.
At the top of your addTasks() method:
  public static void addTasks(int HowManyTasks){
    taskNameArray = new String[HowManyTasks];
    taskDescriptionArray = new String[HowManyTasks];
    developerDetailsArray = new String[HowManyTasks];
    taskDurationArray = new int[HowManyTasks];
    taskIDArray = new String[HowManyTasks];
    StatusArray = new String[HowManyTasks];

    // ... rest of existing addTasks() code ...
    
  }

